# How to return ModelAndView as PDF?

Tags: html, jsp, pdf

I have a page in JSP that have a button as'Create PDF' ,
 how to do so that ?

Like for example on this button click i want to Show a generated pdf of 'www.yahoo.com' .

Comment: You can use itext . Here is a reference of how to: [Spring Web MVC with PDF View Example (using iText 5.x)](https://www.google.gr/search?q=spring%20mvc%20pdf%20view&oq=spring%20mvc%20pdf%20view&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.11848j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=spring%20mvc%20pdf%20view%20resolver%20example)